# How can I inject a service into a Thymeleaf tag processor

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am implementing a custom tag by extending AbstractElementTagProcessor. I'm using latest spring-boot and thymeleaf.

**Is there a way I can access ApplicationContext or to inject a service?**

```
public class ATagProcessor extends AbstractElementTagProcessor {
    ....
    @Override
    protected void doProcess(
        final ITemplateContext context, final IProcessableElementTag tag,
        final IElementTagStructureHandler structureHandler) {
            [Here I need to use a service]
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you inject the service annotating it with @ Service and using @ Autowired in your ATagProcessor class?

Answer (score 0):

annotate ATagProcessor with @Component, then you will be able to use :

```
@Autowired
private MyService myService;
```